# Format string with decimal

Tags: c#

I am trying to take a string that may or may not contain a '.' to x amount of characters removing the "decimal point" as well.  the result will ultimately be converted to a signed integer. I will also always need to the 1/10 decimal (ie 10 will become 100,  1 will become 10, etc...)  I would like to just format the string without converting to an integer until the very end.

Example

if my incoming string is

9.86
I want 98 as a string ( i don't care about rounding up or anything)

if i get 9
I want 90

if i get -100
i want -1000

if i get -95.353
i want -953

Answer (score 2):

```
string.Format("{0:d}", (int)9.015*10);
```

If you want a rounded result, replace the Cast

**Edit:** But I missed the "string" part. Verbose code below

```
var input = "9.86";
var len = input.IndexOf('.');
var result = "";
if (len > 0)
{
    result = input.Substring(0, len);
    result += input.Substring(len + 1, 1);
}
else
{
    result = input + "0";
}
```

Comment: In terms of performance. I would guess it's faster to parse the string to a double than the indexOf and Substring calls to keep it a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are essentially multiplying by ten the number contained in the string and dropping decimal places after the first, then you would be better off casting the string as a decimal and then doing the conversion and casting that number as an integer. Otherwise you will have to write a large set of mathematical rules on how to modify your string based on a particular type of input.

```
        string[] input  = {"9.86", "9", "-100", "-95.3"};
        List<int> intNums = new List<int>();
        foreach (string s in input)
        {
            decimal number;
            if (Decimal.TryParse(s, out number))
            {
                number = number * 10;  
                intNums.Add((int)number);
            }

        }
```

Output:
        [0] 98  int
        [1] 90  int
        [2] -1000   int
        [3] -953    int

Comment: This works, however, I am working is VS 2008, .net 3.5, and sandboxed a bit.  I do not have the Decimal.TryParse method

Comment: The TryParse method is really a check for correct input.  You could skip that and just cast to Decimal:  decimal number = Convert.ToDecimal(s).